# AWS policy to allow serverless deploy to production only to specific user/group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm looking for way to restrict deployment to production assuming I'm not using multiple accounts for dev and prod.

My use case would go as follow (I still not sure if this is possible, pls help me on that). I want to create multiple users into a same account but allow only one user/group to exec commands like sls deploy -s prod and maybe, allow only that user/group to be the only able to create sources name prod_{name}, for example, dynamo tables name prod_users.

Is this possible? or the only way to separate concern is thought the consolidate billing and multiple accounts?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, users don't have any privileges, so you have to explicitly allow them to do something on AWS.
Simplest way to do that is to go to IAM console and create group for users that are allowed to do what you require. After naming group, next step in IAM console is to attach policy to the group. In that step, you would choose CloudFormation, EC2, RDS, ElasticBeanstalk, and whatever services you want them to access. For each service, you can choose more granulary (read, access, admin, ...). You can either choose from AWS predesigned policies, or create one of your own, if it's so specific that it isn't covered by already existing policies.
I'd like to help you further (ie. tell you what policies to include), but for that I'd need to know specific types of users and services that you want covered.
Regards,

Comment: Hi there, I'm aware of this, however, I cannot find any sample about for to do it with users. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you write what specificly you want to allow those users to do, so I can give you more detailed example?

Comment: That would be awesome... it goes a follow. user A and user B... ok both of them can deploy a lambda in mode stage = dev, but only user A can deploy it on stage = prod, does it make sense?

Comment: How are you doing deployment of Lambda? Are you using Serverless application with CloudFormation, or?

Comment: im using the serverless framework which use cloudformation behind the scene, right now, both account has admin rights, I'm looking to remove that and give only permissions as needed

Comment: @andresmijares25 not sure if I managed to capture completely what you're trying to limit, but from what you've told me so far, I think you could add tags to your stages and then add a policy similar to this: `{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": "dev"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: thank you brother, I will take a look at it! at least as starting point it would work :)!